# How to join 2 tables from different databasess

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

Is there any way to join 2 tables from different databases in a query? The first table comes from an MS Access database, and second one come from a SQL Server database

Comment: just extract one into .sql file and then merge it with the second.

Comment: I am affraid that you will have to do the merge in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

you can use OpenRowSet() in sql server management studio to access your accessdb database tables

```
SELECT * From OpenRowset('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
';Database=C:\yourSampleDatabase.mdb;',
'SELECT * from YourTableName') as linkedQueryToAccess
```

and on this result set you can do the join operation with your table present in mssql database

Comment: I want to use this query in vba

Answer (score 0):

You could make a linked server in SQL Server between Access and SQL Server and easily query it. But it would be very slow.